# Error while Integrating POSTMAN with AWS API Gateway. Getting empty List of API Gateway in the drop down

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, integration, amazon-iam

I am trying to integrate my postman collection with AWS API Gateway.
I want this suite to be part of the code build there.

While selecting the value from a list of API Gateways, getting this:[image]

Unable to fetch API Gateways
Something went wrong while fetching API Gateways